# Height 100% for parent div not working in IE11

Tags: css

[image]This code works on Google Chrome, but the height is minimized in IE11; it expands only when I click on the links in menu. And also the font size increases in IE; I need help.
I tried setting the parent div height to 1000px; this way it does not minimize the height. But when you click on the link to display content it does not display all the content. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  height: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container-fluid-full {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #content {
    width: 85.578%;
    padding: 28px;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    margin-left: 14.422% !important;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #sidebar-left {
    background: #eeeeee;
    border-style: solid;
    border-right: thick #edf0f4;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid-full">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <!-- start: Main Menu -->
    <div id="sidebar-left" class="span2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the snippet supposed to show? It is empty in all browsers.

Comment: i did not add all the code because its a lot of code in the content section and on the side bar i have menu with dropdown if you see the picture above its a screenshot of ie the white section is the content div but its minimized to that size instead of full page height i  have added another screenshot in chrome